# Dropdown menu hides behind images

Tags: javascript, css, web, blogger

The dropdown menu of my blog gets behind the image slider on the main page.
http://allfacebookgames.blogspot.com/

How do I avoid it so the the dropdown menu is not covered?

For your information, the dropdown menu does not require any javascript and solely depends upon css.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fix it:

```
#menu-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 40;
}
```

To show that it works: http://www.csspivot.com/t0Sj3

Comment: Thank you, also could you explain what function does position: relative; do? I thought z-index was solely responsible for outward positioning the elements.

Comment: @JohnMerchant I think you will get quite a lot of information from this video ( fullscreen it ) http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/40-how-z-index-works/ It doesn't go too deep, but I think it should tell you enough of how it works. And another site https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/Adding_z-index

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will certainly watch it.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:relative` and `z-index:9999` on the `#menu-wrapper` rule